# How to add run time changing between android apps with java as backend

Tags: java, android, mysql, spring-mvc, runtime

I'm developing two same android app with 2 text fields and with two buttons. These apps are connected to server with backend java servlets and mysql database. When i click on first button i send request to server and update database . On the second app when i click second button they recieve recently updation and print on text fields. My question is how can i make my app changes text runtime if first or second app update database or execute buisness logic. E.g if first app http call to server and perform some buisness logic after execution at same time second will show these changing without produce any http call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question currently then you are trying to achieve the following:

1. User 1 adds a value to the text field and presses update
2. User 2 gets the updated value from the user 1 once he presses fetch latest

The logic involved to get the above-mentioned functionality working:

1. send HTTP Post request once the user 1 clicks update button
2. One the server side update the value in the MySQL database
3. On the server side send a message using Firebase Cloud Messaging
4. In the Android app create a receive message method using Firebase Cloud Messaging
5. If there is a message then update the text field for the second user
6. IF you want the second user to press the "Fetch" button then you can execute receive message method after the button press.

Refer:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ - For sending and receiving the messages

Comment: Is there possible without firebase??

Comment: If you want to skip firebase then you can choose any other backend platform for your Android app.